# 'on_activated' event listener and project switching

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

`on_activated` is supposed to be called "when a view gains input focus" (ST3 API docs). When I switch to a different project/workspace with `cmd+control+p` in ST3, `on_activated` gets called for all views in the working space/project. So it might be called 10 times or more. I find that behavior unexpected and would like to just get one call for the currently visible view. So why not just once for the view that gains input focus with the project switch? Any workarounds?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the code.

```py
import sublime_plugin

class TestPlugin(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    count = 0

    def on_activated(self, view):
        self.count += 1
        print('"on_activated" event fired %ith time!' % self.count)
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using. Also, are you using ST2 or ST3? The tag says 2, but you mention 3 in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just added the code. I am using ST3 but the API for `on_activated` didn't change so I thought it's relevant for ST2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the currently activated view is the one you want to.

```
import sublime_plugin

class TestPlugin(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    count = 0

    def on_activated(self, view):
        if self.view.window().active_view().id() == view.id():
            print('"on_activated" successfully fired!')
        else:
            self.count += 1
            print('"on_activated": %i unsuccessful fired.' % self.count)
```